# SPFX Add webpart dynamically at runtime

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, react

I'm trying to render webparts dynamically at runtime. I have almost no experience with react, so this is where I'm stuck (I think).

Using pnp-js I can get the webpart definition and manifest like this:

```
const page = await ClientSidePage.fromFile(sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/SitePages/Home.aspx"));
const partDefs = await sp.web.getClientSideWebParts();
const partDef = partDefs.find(c => c.Id === "e377ea37-9047-43b9-8cdb-a761be2f8e09")
const part = ClientSideWebpart.fromComponentDef(partDef);
const manifest = JSON.parse(partDef.Manifest)
console.group("WebPartDefinition + Manifest")
console.log(partDef)
console.log(manifest)
console.log(part)
console.groupEnd()
```

Next I tried using `_spComponentLoader.loadComponentById` to load the actual component based on the `manifest.id`. I also was able to load `@microsoft/sp-webpart-base`

```
// @microsoft/sp-webpart-base
const Base = (await _spComponentLoader.loadComponentById('974a7777-0990-4136-8fa6-95d80114c2e0'))
const Component = (await _spComponentLoader.loadComponentById(manifest.id)).default
console.log(Base)
console.log(Component)
```

Next I tried rendering the component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Component, null), document.querySelector('.SPCanvas'))
```

However, `sp-pages-assembly` throws an error when rendering: `TypeError: Cannot set property '_isDisposed' of undefined`.

I believe the component creation is wrong. I know I'm not passing in any props for the component, but this seems to be unrelated - the error stems from `this` being `undefined`  in `sp-pages-assembly`.

Comment: why would you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to be able to create pages dynamically. For example I'm considering using this to create a master-webpart, where multiple other webparts are added depending on the properties passed to the master.

Comment: Are you looking for any of this: [Build Custom App Pages with SharePoint Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-custom-app-pages-with-sharepoint-framework/) || [Create Modern Pages and update metadata using SPFx Extensions](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/03/13/create-modern-pages-and-update-metadata-using-spfx-extensions-sp-pnp-js-and-azure-functions/)

Comment: Hi @Johannes, dis you ever find a solution for this? I am trying to load a YammerEmberWebpart in another webpart, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: No sorry, I didn't follow up on this.